# Visual Studio 2010: How create new web project from existing code?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, project, solution, suo

I've a working website without project / solution. 
How can I generate a new project from this code? 
Thanx

Comment: Can you not just open the website via file -> open website?

Comment: Yes but I don't have a "solution / project" then...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you [Create a Project from Existing Code Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/754c3hy7.aspx)

Comment: I don't have that on my "file" menu... I'm only able to create a new project from scracth...

Comment: That's not the answer; the article linked is for Visual Studio 2013

Answer (score 4):

Just to be ultra clear for everyone. In Visual Studio 2010 Express, do the following:

1. Tools menu, Settings, Expert Settings
2. File menu, New Project ... create your project
3. File menu, Add, Existing Web site

Answer (score 3):

Create a New solution from scratch, then choose add web existing website.

Point to the directory for your current code.